# CSS won't work on every link with same class

Tags: html, css, properties

i've got the following code:

```
a.navigation, a:active.navigation, a:visited.navigation {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 4px 0px 6px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
a:hover.navigation {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #c53838;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Which technically should give the properties to every link that has the class "navigation".  But it doesn't. Only the first link gets the properties. I don't know if they don't get any property but at least only the first gets the border-radius property.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="navigation">Startseite</a>
<a href="lexikon.html" class="navigation">Lexikon</a>
<a href="historie.html" class="navigation">Historie</a>
and more
```

Every link shall look like this when hovered

[image: http://itbild.de//img/eb92937b69eeb7650aaf2095d4616860Bildschirmfoto-2011-12-10-um-15.59.59.png]

But the second, third and fourth look like this

[image: http://itbild.de//img/5aa767cef505bb4745f5b42a58d05e5cBildschirmfoto-2011-12-10-um-16.00.08.png]

Comment: Do you have a live link? As cannot reproduce with your code in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/aAyL5/1/ (CSS code has been very slightly changed - but is still fundamentally what you posted

Answer (score 3):

You have written your selectors wrong. The pseudo-selectors must come after the class, as in

```
a.navigation:hover
```

As [the spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax),

> One pseudo-element may be appended to the last simple selector in a
>   chain, in which case the style information applies to a subpart of
>   each subject.

Comment: Oh, okey. But this doesnt fix it. But thanks anyways for the advice.